# Webpack Cli TypeError: Cannot read property 'getArguments' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react js application and I am trying to implement webpack to create a build and deploy it to IIS.

I am getting this below error when I try to build the application using webpack:

```
C:\webpackProj>npm run build
> webpackProj@10.4.0 build
> webpack --mode development
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read property 'getArguments' of undefined
at WebpackCLI.getBuiltInOptions (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:755:63)
at makeCommand.options.entry (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:880:32)
at async WebpackCLI.makeCommand (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:395:31)
at async loadCommandByName (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:876:17)
at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1272:17)
at async Command.parseAsync (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:935:5)
at async WebpackCLI.run (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1296:9)
at async runCLI (C:\webpackProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js:9:9)
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "webpackProj",
  "version": "10.4.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^25.3.0",
  "@ag-grid-enterprise/rich-select": "^25.1.0",
  "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.21.0",
  "@emotion/core": "^10.1.1",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
  "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
  "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
  "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
  "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
  "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.18",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
  "ag-grid-autocomplete-editor": "^2.2.1",
  "ag-grid-community": "^25.1.0",
  "ag-grid-enterprise": "^25.1.0",
  "ag-grid-react": "^25.1.0",
  "apexcharts": "^3.28.1",
  "axios": "^0.21.4",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
  "browserslist": "^4.17.0",
  "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
  "classnames": "^2.2.6",
  "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
  "d3": "^6.7.0",
  "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
  "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
  "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
  "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
  "html-to-draftjs": "^1.5.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
  "jquery": "^3.6.0",
  "jquery-mask-plugin": "^1.14.16",
  "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
  "js2xmlparser": "^4.0.1",
  "moment": "^2.29.1",
  "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^1.7.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
  "npx": "^10.2.2",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
  "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
  "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
  "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.2.0",
  "react-calendar-heatmap": "^1.8.1",
  "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
  "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
  "react-datepicker": "^3.8.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
  "react-draggable": "^4.4.4",
  "react-dropdown-select": "^4.7.4",
  "react-items-carousel": "^2.8.0",
  "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
  "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
  "react-loading-screen": "0.0.17",
  "react-multi-select-component": "^3.1.7",
  "react-picky": "^5.3.2",
  "react-radio-buttons": "^1.2.2",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
  "react-router": "^5.2.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
  "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
  "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
  "react-sweet-progress": "^1.1.2",
  "react-toastify": "^6.2.0",
  "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
  "reactstrap": "^8.10.0",
  "redux": "^4.1.1",
  "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
  "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
  "save": "^2.4.0",
  "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
  "sweetalert2": "^9.17.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "build:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build:qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts build",
    "build:uat": "env-cmd -f .env.uat react-scripts build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
    "ie 11",
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Webpack.config file

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.export = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'main.[hash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "html-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|png)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: port,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true
    }
}
```

.babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ]
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you ever find out what you are missing?  I'm running into this as well, and I'm at a loss

Comment: for me it was webpack cli version, after downgrading to "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0", it worked

Answer (score 3):

Marik Ishtar's reply above worked for me. I downgraded from the current version of webpack-cli to version 3.3.0.

```
yarn add webpack-cli@3.3.0
```